# How to access json data

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently running into a problem, and I'm unable to find the solution.

I do a request to a REST-Service and grab some data...

```
var test = responseData._bodyInit;
console.log(test);

06-23 03:43:14.383 12800 12832 I ReactNativeJS: {"search_time": 92, "results": [{"item": {"name": "Profil", "url": "https://www.someurl.tdl", "custom": "bla", "content": null, "trackable": false, "uuid": "otheruuid"}, "image": {"thumb_120": "morebla", "uuid": "someuuid"}, "score": 69}]}
```

So far so good, but I only want to have the "url"... so I tried:

```
console.log(test['results'][0].item.url);
```

and receive the following log:

```
06-23 03:43:14.398 12800 12832 I ReactNativeJS: { [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'test['results'][0]')]

06-23 03:43:14.398 12800 12832 I ReactNativeJS: line: 1340,

06-23 03:43:14.398 12800 12832 I ReactNativeJS: column: 40,

06-23 03:43:14.398 12800 12832 I ReactNativeJS: sourceURL: 'http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false' }
```

Comment: Maybe `test` is a JSON string that hasn't been parsed yet? Try `JSON.parse(test).results[0].item.url` instead?

Comment: Or try `console.log(typeof(test))` to check.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
var url = JSON.parse(j).results[0].item.url;
```